# Memory Leak in WMI and possible solution

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, wmi

So we have a memory leak in our application and we think it's from WMI calls.

This is the code where we think is the leak:

```
private ThermalInfo()
{
    // ==============  Temperature

    var mgmtTempScope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\WMI");
    var oQuery = new ObjectQuery("select * from MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
    ManagementObjectSearcher oTempSearch = null;
    ManagementObjectCollection collection = null;

    try
    {
        oTempSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(mgmtTempScope, oQuery);
        collection = oTempSearch.Get();

        foreach (var obj in collection)
        {
            mTemperature = Convert.ToDouble(obj.Properties["CurrentTemperature"].Value) / 10 - 273.2;
            mValid = true;
            obj.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
        // Not supported
        mTemperature = 0;
        mValid = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (collection != null)
            collection.Dispose();
        if (oTempSearch != null)
            oTempSearch.Dispose();


        FlushMemory();
    }
}
```

And here the FlushMemory():

```
 [DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr process, int minimumWorkingSetSize, int maximumWorkingSetSize);
        public static void FlushMemory()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            {
                SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
            }
        }
```

Our Application (it's actually a service) kept growing and growing - and the only thing that it was doing was calling this Method and setting the mTemperatur and mValid. With the FlushMemory Call the leak stopped and i could run the service the whole night without any growth in memory. 
The only problem i have now is that the service won't let itself stop anymore. Everytime i want to stop the service it's never stopping and i always have to forcestop it with taskkill or the taskmanager.

Could someone please help me with this? Also how can i avoid the leak in the WMI calls? I've got w8.1 so there shouldn'T be a problem anymore but i guess there is...

Comment: Stahp. Stop using that `FlushMemory` method. Pick up a memory profiler and find what is holding the memory. Don't unnecessary force `GC.Collect` which is way to invite performance problems. You can use any memory profiler. ANTS profiler, or even the one which comes with visual studio.

Comment: Yeah - and i cannot find any hold of any references - and the leak only happens when we use the WMI calls. The FlushMemory keeps us at a stable 27,000kb whereas without the FlushMemory it rises endlessly...

Answer (score 0):

we are seeing similar problem: ManagementClass, etc creates large memory leak, even with  proper use of using(..){..} and Dispose().
Searching stackoverflow and elsewhere we see it is a common problem.

Calling **GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() once**, which is part of the FlushMemory() above, **is enough to fix it** (GC.Collect() is not needed)

though we do not consider it a solution really, just a workaround.